# moving image in a div by mouse draging and generating the css dynamically

Tags: css

I want to implement an image/div drag functionality like the one in the tinymce, 
when the user click on the image, its border are selected and one can move the image/div around in the editor, and in the meanwhile it generate inline css as well..

Thanks...

Comment: you probably need Javascript for this to be possible. try jQuery!

Comment: the question was originally tagged with "jquery"

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like [jQuery UI's draggables](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#default), which allows you to make dragging movements with your mouse which will alter the dragged element's CSS accordingly. Use the `start` and `stop` events if you want to change the border color when it is being dragged.

Comment: Thanks David Hedlund... This is the functionality I was looking for.
Thanks for your answer.
:)